# Removing java source folders for a Maven reactor project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When checking out a reactor project with multiple projects m2eclipse insists in creating the /src/{main,test}/{java,resources}  folders even though the projects' packaging type is `pom`.

[image: src folders in eclipse]

How can I instruct m2eclipse to not create source folders for `pom` projects?

Comment: I've never seen this. Which version of m2e are you running?

Comment: I'm using the latest 1.1 nightly. However, deleting the project settings and reimporting seems to have worked. Flaky :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use Eclipse Indigo try deleting:

- .classpath
- .project
- .settings
- src

And then on your eclipse project: Refres + Maven > Update Project configuration